# Stripe country dropdown is cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I implemented the payment stripe provided but there seems to be a overflow problem with the country drop-down. I do not know how to fix it.[image]

```
<form action="/payment" method="POST" id="payment-form">
            @csrf
            <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_y4qlFbPkJ2trQLaMuzvNJqci00RqQb1K3W"
            data-amount="1499"
            data-name="Finalfees"
            data-description="Premium Subscription"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-email="{{ Auth::user()->email }}"
            data-zip-code=true
            data-billing-address=true
            data-currency="USD">
            </script>
          </form>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that causes this?

Comment: @HPierce Yep I just re-edited my post

Comment: This is probably a CSS problem, or there's some ridiculously long name in there wrecking the layout.

Comment: What browser (make, version, platform) are you seeing this in?

Comment: @duck Google Chrome